# In Java, using the java.nio library and a FileChannel, how can I load a Properties object from a file?

Tags: java, properties, file-locking, java.nio.file

In a Java program, I am given a `java.nio.Path` object and I need to lock a file, and then load a `java.util.Properties` object from it.

I read that the proper way to get a shared lock for a file, represented as a `Path`, is to get a `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` lock it with a shared lock `channel.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true)`

```
final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ);
final FileLock lock = channel.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
```

Now that I have locked the channel, I assume that I should now reference that channel when I am loading my properties file.

However, I don't see a simple way to translate a `FileChannel` into something that is readable by `Properties`. `Properties` takes an `InputStream`, or a `Reader`. I could implement my own reader, but I'm sure my team would rather I use something out-of-the-box, if available.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Is my underlying assumption incorrect? If so, what is the proper flow for this procedure?

Comment: What's with all the locking and `FileChannel` complication? Regular property file reading is really simple.

Comment: I expect external processes to be writing to this file. I don't want to try to load the properties at the same time as another process is modifying it.

Comment: Seems like file based communication might be a bad fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you missed the existence of the [`Channels`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/channels/Channels.html) helper class:

```
Properties properties=new Properties();

try(final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(filePath, StandardOpenOption.READ);
    final FileLock lock = channel.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true)) {

    properties.load(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
}
```